# how long do things in the windows 8 future access list last

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

if I add an item to the future access list in a windows store app, will it stay accessible the next time the app is run? after the machine has been turned off?

or does it only last as long as the app is running

Answer (score 2):

The future access list is persistent across app sessions, reboots, app upgrades, etc. That's its whole purpose.

To expand on the idea a little, because StorageFolder and StorageFile are abstractions for pathnames--and accommodate folders and files on storage systems that cannot be represented by pathnames--you use the access cache instead of saving pathname strings in your app data. For this reason, consider the access cache a specialized method of app data storage, specifically for saving file references + permissions.